# Need clarification on how ScheduledTaskAgent and BackgroundTransferService work

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need some clarification on how these 2 entities interact...

If I use the BackgroundTransferService only to upload some files, the moment I move away from the application, the upload will stop.  When I come back to the application, the upload will resume.  Is that correct?  Or is the upload lost?

However, if I wanted to make sure that the file will upload regardless of whether the user moves away from the application, I should kick off the BackgroundTransferService upload inside of a class that implements the ScheduledTaskAgent.  Is that correct?  If this is the case, how can that be done?  BackgroundTransferService reports its progress via Events, thus I can't call NotifyComplete from the OnInvoke method of the ScheduleTaskAgent.

Am I going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not correct. If the background transfer is initiated, it is inserted in a queue that is dependent on a set of multiple factors, including other pending background transfers (from other third-party application) and the general network speed. You can find additional details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202955%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). That queue is processed, even if the application is tombstoned.

Comment: In your experience, are you able to replicate this behavior (e.g. BackgroundTransferService working while app is not active) in the emulator?

Comment: Yes. It is working fine for me. Experiment with this sample: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219083